# AX 2012 Database - BaseEnum to String

Tags: enums, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I am trying to Code a "while select" Statement.

I have a table "CarBrandTable" with two fields:

CarBrandId and Countries.

CarBrandId is a String. 
Countries is a Base Enum.

Now I want to get the Data, by asking with a select Statement.

When I want to retrieve the Data by saying info(carBrandTable.countries);

The Compiler says... "Argument 'txt' is incompatible with the required type"

I know that my baseenum is not a string and that I hvae to somehow convert it. 
But I have Trouble in doing so.

Does anybody have a tip for me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Rephrase the info like this:

```
info(strFmt('%1', carBrandTable.countries));
```

Answer (score 3):

Other way is `enum2str` function.

```
info(enum2str(carBrandTable.countries));
```